# Is the Unicode code point value equal to the UTF-16BE representation for every character?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16

I saved some strings in Microsoft Agenda in Unicode big endian format (UTF-16BE). When I open it with the shell command `xxd` to see the binary value, write it down, and get the value of the Unicode code point by [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html) to get the ordinal value character by character (this is a python built-in function which takes a one-character Unicode string and returns the code point value), and compare them, I find they are equal.

But I think that the Unicode code point value is  different to UTF-16BE — one is a code point; the other is an encoding format. Some of them are equal, but maybe they are different for some characters.

Is the Unicode code point value equal to the UTF-16BE encoding representation for every character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, codepoints outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane use *two* UTF-16 words (so 4 bytes).

For codepoints in the U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+FFFF ranges, the codepoint and UTF-16 encoding map one-to-one.

For codepoints in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF, two words in the range U+D800 to U+DFFF are used; a lead surrogate from 0xD800 to 0xDBFF and a trail surrogate from 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF.

See the [UTF-16 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) on the nitty gritty details.

So, most UTF-16 big-endian bytes, when printed, can be mapped directly to Unicode codepoints. For UTF-16 little-endian you just swap the bytes around. For UTF-16 words in starting with a 0xD8 through to 0xDF byte, you'll have to map surrogates to the actual codepoint.